# Passing arrays in Perl

Tags: perl

All right, I'll try to explain what I've done so far. I'm using a Parellel::ForkManager to grab data from an array of URLs, which is then stored in variables (value1, value2, value3).

I then collect the data from all of those processes, and display the data with `$pm->run_on_finish`.

```
#...
my $pm = new Parallel::ForkManager(10);

$pm->run_on_finish (
    sub {
        my @info = @{$data_structure_reference};

        print $info[0];
        print $info[1];
        print $info[2];
    }
);

for my $var (@urls) {

    $pm->start and next;
    #...
    @returned = &something($var);
    #...
    $pm->finish(0, \@returned);

}

sub something {

    #... getting data from each URL and storing it in variables

    my @array = (
        $value1,
        $value2,
        $value3
    );
    return @array;
}
```

Now, what I *want* to do, is to pass an array, `@value4`, as well, and then only display that data if there is something in the array. So, I want it to look like this:

```
sub something {

    #... getting data from each URL and storing it in variables

    my @array = (
        $value1,
        $value2,
        $value3,
        @value4
    );
    return @array;
}
```

And then I want it to print that array, only if there is something in it.

Unfortunately, I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: pass an array @value4 to _what_ function? Please clarify.

Comment: @hexcoder clarification has arrived?  I think what cespinoza has answered with is helpful. I'm going to see what I can do with it... and then probably upvote/accept

Comment: @Aelfhere Why do you need to bother with references at all? You use the three first values, what's left in the array is whatever would be in your `@value4` array.

Comment: @Aelfhere ok, if the answer fits, fine. (For me it is still unclear what you really wanted, but that is not relevant anymore).

Comment: @hexcoder Each fork runs the `something()` sub and gets values, which are then printed in the `finish()` statement. He wanted to know how to pass on the values through the `finish()` statement.

Comment: @TLP thanks for the explanation. So `\@returned` is `$data_structure_reference`, right?

Comment: @hexcoder Yep, although it's not explicitly referenced in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that what you are asking is how to return an array along with the three scalars returned from the `something()` sub, and print it?

I also assume that those three scalars are what's referred to as being in `@info`.

The simplest way seems to me to be to simply tack them to the end of the array you return, use the three first values, and if there's anything left, print that too.

```
$pm->run_on_finish (
    sub {
        my @info = @{$data_structure_reference};

        print splice @info, 0, 3;
        print @info if (@info);
    }
);

sub something {
    return (
            $value1,
            $value2,
            $value3,
            @value4
        );
}
```

As you'll notice, you do not need to fill a dummy array for the return value, simply return values inside the parens. You do not need to dereference the array, since you can use the `@info` array straight up if you splice off the first three values.

I like it simple. If it works.

Comment: this is exactly what I needed.  The simplicity of it shows just how little I know of the language lol.  Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

I've previously provided a simple solution to this problem. It can use threads (`use threads;`) or processes (`use forks;`).

```
use threads;  # or: use forks;
use Thread::Queue qw( );

use constant NUM_WORKERS => 10;

my $request_q  = Thread::Queue->new();
my $response_q = Thread::Queue->new();

# Create the workers.
for (1..NUM_WORKERS) {
   (async {
      while (defined(my $request = $request_q->dequeue())) {
         $response_q->enqueue(process_request($request));
      }
   })->detach();
}

# Submit work to workers.
$request_q->enqueue(@requests);

# Signal the workers they are done.
$request_q->enqueue(undef) for 1..NUM_WORKERS;

# Collect the results.
my $working = NUM_WORKERS;
while ($working) {
   my $result = $response_q->dequeue();
   if (!defined($result)) {
       --$working;
       next;
   }
   process_response($result);
}
```

The work to be done in the children is done by `process_request`.

```
sub process_request {
    # ...

    return [
        $value1,
        $value2,
        $value3,
        \@value4,
    ];
}
```

The results are passed to `process_response` in the parent.

```
sub process_response {
    my ($value1, $value2, $value3, $value4) = @{ $_[0] };
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 great prototype code! @Aelfhere: it is more elegant to work with references

Comment: This is great.  I was able to go with TLP's answer for this, but just for fun I played with what you answered and it works as well. Thanks!  @hexcoder I will remember to be elegant... in the future :)

Comment: @hexcoder, @Aelfhere, I've updated my code so the results are processed by the parent as they come in instead of waiting for all the work to be done. (Untested, just like the original code.)

Answer (score 1):

I am not totally sure what you are asking, but in order to pass multiple arrays to a function in Perl one must pass by reference.

```
my @array1 = (1, 2, 3);
my @array2 = ('a', 'b', 'c');

&fn(\@array1, \@array2);
```

In order to print an array only in the case when it has value, one must simply check that it has value and print it:

```
print "@array" if @array;
```

Though, the nice function of `"@array"` is that if `@array` has no value then `"@array"` evaluates to `""`. This allows you to reduce the previous statement to a simple:

```
print "@array"
```